# Entity.SaveChanges() also saves removed object of a BindingList?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, bindinglist

I hope you can help me out, I've being scratching my head the whole night trying to figure out where this bug persist.

I'm writing an invoicing application in winform.

I have a grid on the form with its data source set to a BindingList object.

Let's just it's along the lines of:

```
BindingList<InvoiceLine> MyInvoiceLines = new BindingList<InvoiceLine> { };

Invoice MyInvoice = new Invoice();
```

Both InvoiceLine and Invoice are entity objects in my model.

I add lines to the grid via:

```
MyInvoiceLines.Add(new InvoiceLine());
```

I remove lines from the grid via:

```
MyInvoiceLines.Remove(LineToBeRemoved);
```

Where LineToBeRemoved is a property that gets the selected line when use wants to remove the line etc...

So eventually I want to save the invoice, so I do this...

```
 foreach(var line in MyInvoiceLines)
{
   MyInvoice.InvoiceLines.Add(line);
}
```

and then calls SaveChange(). However the lines that was removed from InvoiceLines BindingList are also saved... I've being scratching my head trying to work this out as NO WHERE in my code from start to finish does the InvoiceLines collection gets referenced or was connected with the data context object before this method which eventually action the save.

This is a simplified version of my code but I can't help thinking I must got some thing conceptually wrong either with the BindingList or with the data context object. It really isn't obvious for me as I'm a noob.

Any help would be appreciated, not after a fix, maybe some tools or method where I can further diagnose this problem...

Update: detaching the item before adding to the BindingList seemingly *fixed* it but deleting the object from entity has strange behaviours :/ thanks everyone.

Comment: Please post your code and tell us where the error occurs and under what condtions.

Comment: Sorry I hit submit too soon. I've updated the OP. Let me know if you require more info.

Comment: Did you check if `MyInvoiceLines.Remove(LineToBeRemoved)` actually worked and that `MyInvoiceLines` in your foreach loop really doesn't contain the removed items anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting the object explictly. i.e.

```
foreach(var object in deletedObjectCollection)
{
     _currentContext.DeleteObject(order);
}
```

rather than rely on it's absence in a collection to activate a delete. In my experience (with EF4) that doesn't work. I use lazy loading and the absence of an object in the collection could be because it hasn't been loaded so it doesn't feel right to rely on it's absence. There is probably (almost certainly) more elegant ways to do this but it is currently working for me.

Generally I've had to do a lot more explicitly with EF than I though i would.

Comment: I tried to delete explicitly but now the removed object is added and the NON - removed is removed wtf.... lol maybe it's time to rewrite this whole thing.

Comment: Oh no @Rillanon. Are you sure you have two collections built and are deleting the correct one? obvious - sorry. Also - not pretty but try calling saveChanges after each delete loop just to see if that does the trick. The delete object call should work

Comment: Just checked again... nope just one collection, this is doing my head in :( oh well time for bed, night night. thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

The entity that has been removed from the BindingList, has at also bee detached from the DBContext?

If the entity is still attached to the context it will still be tracked and therefore changes will be saved.

Comment: I tried calling the entity.InvoiceLines.detach(LineToBeRemoved) however it's still saved... the thing is the entity was never meant to be attached before the save method. The removal method happens before this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set one dirty flag for unchanged record and then check it in Entity.SaveChages() event.
May be this help to you...

Answer (score 0):

You do this multiple times? You may have added all the `InvoiceLine` items to your `Invoice`, then removed some from the `BindingList` (not your actual entity!), and then re-add them to your entity.

I suppose (but to be honest I'm a little unsure about this point) as the primary keys match, duplicates aren't saved twice. However, the items that are supposed to be removed are still there.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Invoice` object is an `Entity` object it is context-aware and will be tracked by the context. Calling `SaveChanges()` will save all changes for all `Entity` objects unless they are detached.

Keep in mind that if you relate these `Entity` objects to an object graph and attach any node of the object graph to the context, the entire graph will be attched. So if you create a new entity object, like an `InvoiceLine`, and you relate this new `InvoiceLine` to an object graph:

```
MyInvoiceLines.Add(new InvoiceLine());
```

the entire graph should be tracked by the context at this point.